# Immidiate and latent effects of modifying my own kernel binary at runtime?

Tags: macos, kernel

I'm more of a web-developer and database guy, but severely inconvenient performance issues relating to `kernel_task` and temperature on my personal machine have made me interested in digging into the details of my Mac OS (I notices some processes would trigger long-lasting spikes in kernel-task, despite consistently low CPU temperature and newly re-imaged machine).

I am a root user on my own OSX machine. I can read `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel`. My understanding is this is "[Mach](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH209-TPXREF101)/[XNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU)" Kernel of this machine (although I don't know a lot about those, but I'm surprised that it's only 13Mb).

What happens if I modify or delete `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel`?

I imagine since it's at run-time, [things might be okay until I try to reboot](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1832493). **If this is the case, would carefully modifying this file change the behavior of my OS, only effective on reboot**, presuming it didn't cause a kernel panic? (is kernel-panic only a linux thing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if I modify or delete `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel`?

First off, you'll need to disable SIP (system integrity protection) in order to be able to modify or edit this file, as it's protected even from the root user by default for security reasons.

If you delete it, your system will no longer boot. If you replace it with a different xnu kernel, that kernel will in theory boot next time, assuming it's sufficiently matched to both the installed device drivers and other kexts, and the OS userland.

Note that you don't need to delete/replace the kernel file to boot a different one, you can have more than one installed at a time. For details, see the documentation that comes with Apple's Kernel Debug Kits (KDKs) which you can download from the [Apple Developer Downloads Area](https://developer.apple.com/download/more).

> I imagine since it's at run-time, things might be okay until I try to reboot.

Yes, the kernel is loaded into memory by the bootloader early on during the boot process; the file isn't used past that, except for producing prelinked kernels when your device drivers change.

Finally, I feel like I should explain a little about what you actually seem to be trying to diagnose/fix:

> but severely inconvenient performance issues relating to kernel_task and temperature on my personal machine have made me interested in digging into the details of my Mac OS

`kernel_task` runs more code than just the `kernel` core itself. Specifically, any kexts that are loaded (see `kextstat` command) - and there are a lot of those on a modern macOS system - are loaded into kernel space, meaning they are counted under `kernel_task`.

Long-running spikes of kernel CPU usage sound like they might be caused by file system self-maintenance, or volume encryption/decryption activity. They are almost certainly not basic programming errors in the xnu kernel itself. (Although I suppose stupid mistakes are easy to make.)

Another possible culprits are device drivers; especially GPU drivers are incredibly complex pieces of software, and of course are busy even if your system is seemingly idle.

The first step to dealing with this problem - if there indeed is one - would be to find out what the kernel is actually doing with those CPU cycles. So for that you'd want to do some profiling and/or tracing. Doing this on the running kernel most likely again requires SIP to be disabled. The Instruments.app that ships with Xcode is able to profile processes; I'm not sure if it's still possible to profile `kernel_task` with it, I think it at least used to be possible in earlier versions. Another possible option is DTrace. (there are entire books written on this topic)